# Displacement from accelerometer data with filtering

Tags: matlab, accelerometer, butterworth

I have acceleration data from few accelerometer sensors. I am interested in the displacement so, I double integrate it (cumtrapz in matlab). The acceleration data is really noisy so, I use Butterworth filter to filter out the low frequency noises. After the first integration, I get the velocity and then filter this velocity to further integrate to get displacement. Everything works just fine. The only issue I have is that after filtering I lose the actual value of the acceleration and thus the value of the displacement I get does not make any sense.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you use the actual value of the acceleration? What does this mean? I am not sure if it is advisable to filter the integrated signal again. And you may want to use a bandpass filter (not just a high pass filter) as the accelerometer is only valid in a certain range of frequencies (most likely it is valid at low frequencies but not at very high frequencies, so you should at least use a lowpass filter rather than a highpass filter)

Comment: I get the acceleration value in terms of g so, I multiply by 9.8 to get the acceleration in terms of ms^-2. Now, I did not filter the integrated velocity signal to get displacement. It does not have any dramatic effect. If I use low pass butter filter, then I get displacement that increases exponentially, which is far from the reality.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with using higher order butterworth Filters and was able to solve it by experimenting with different cut off frequencies.

Comment: Could you add more detail about how you were able to solve the problem?